# Using parameters within parameter in Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a set of parameters (e.g. $StartTime, $EndTime, $Flag) to be passed to a batch file. I would like to have these parameters themselves as a single parameter, passed to the batch file and then used within the batch file. How do I do this?

TIA

Comment: Much depends on the format of your parameters and why you need to pass them as a single parameter. More details required.

Comment: Actually the requirement is, I have a number of 'command' tasks inside an ETL tool, each task will have 'almost' same command with parameters repeating. So I thought it would be parameterise these into single parameter (easy to maintain) and pass that one parameter to batch file.

Comment: Parameters typically contain date-time values and strings; The values would be (ETL) mapping name, followed by start datetime, end datetime, success flag etc. which are passed to a batch file which writes these values to a text (log) file.

Comment: Have you tried to put quotes (`""`) around the whole parameter set when passing it to the batch file?

Comment: Yes, the output is just parameters within double quotes!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo %*
```

don't bother "packaging" the parameters - just string them together.

Comment: The ETL tool does not apply the (individual) param value referenced within the single parameter when calling the batch file.. Without this, there is not much point in tweaking the batch file itself.. I am currently trying for some workaround.. Thanks anyway!